# How not to lose a get in json after migrating from localhost to server?

Tags: json, vue.js, localhost

I'm consuming a `.json` file on my localhost and everything is working fine. However, now I would like to deploy and localhost will no longer work.

This is part of the code:

```
// BurgerForm.vue

methods: {
  async getIngredients() {

    const req = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/ingredients");
    const data = await req.json();

    this.breads = data.breads;
    this.meats = data.meats;
  },
…
}
```

In order for me to run localhost I run the following backend in my `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
  "build": "vue-cli-service build",
  "backend": "json-server --watch db/db.json"
},
```

The structure of the files I mentioned is like this:

> `/db/db.json`
>
> `/src/components/BurgerForm.vue`

So how do I keep querying and getting data from json after I migrate to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find [Webpack Dev Server](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver) useful.

Assuming you don't mind making your API available under a path on the main system, if you add the following to your `vue.config.js`:

```json
devServer: {
   //...other options may be necessary
   proxy: {
        "/path/to/api/*": {
             target: "http://localhost:3000",
             secure: false,
             changeOrigin: true
        }
   }
}
```

Once you start your front-end app using `npm run serve` if you make a request to the `/path/to/api/ingredients` targeted at the same server, i.e. `fetch("/path/to/api/ingredients")`, the dev server will proxy the request to `http://localhost:3000/ingredients` automatically.